# Convert vector<string> to 2D vector<int> without vector<vector<int>>?

Tags: c++

I've got a 2D vector of strings:

```
AAB
BAB
BAA
```

And I want to build a 2D vector of integers based on what values it finds at each `[i][j]`, which I have already done this using a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to produce:

```
110
010
011
```

But this is proving problematic for a later use of the 2D vector of integers as I need to use it in a BFS but as a `std::vector<int>`. So is there a way to keep the 2D schema without using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of having two vectors and indexing as `v[i][j]`, you can use one vector and index as `v[t]`. The size of your vector will be `w * h` instead of having vectors of size `w` (width) and size `h` (height).

You can use the single value `t` as an index. Here `t = i + j * w`, and `w` is the row width, in your case `w=3`.

Comment: How is the implementation? myvector.insert(t, num)? Of what type is `t`, `int`?

Comment: using `v[t]` does fill a vector, however when I try to `cout` it is producing a single line of all the elements (real size is 15x30, so 450 ints) and a lot of `0` values that are not actually there.

Comment: How are you assigning the values? Did you resize the vector to 450 first?